# How do I specify that a DLL is a library using Dotfuscator CE on the command line?

Tags: .net-framework

I'm trying to get the command line parameters for Dotfuscator Community Edition v5.0.2600 working with the prefixing to specify that a DLL is a library. The help says the following:

`/in:[+|-]<file>[,[+|-]<file>]  specify input assemblies. Use prefix to obfuscate input as public(+) or private(-) assembly`

Yet when I try the following command line:

`dotfuscator /in:-MyLib.dll`

...I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried with and without enclosing quotation marks without success. Is the parser faulty, or do I have wrong syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path such as `dotfuscator /in:-C:\foobar\lib.dll`. I've noticed with the professional version that full paths are required in most places

Comment: That did not work either I'm afraid. Got a different error message though. "The given path's format is not supported".

Comment: @Nilzor Ah, I was afraid I'd be wrong. You should probably try taking this question to the Dotfuscator support forum then: http://www.preemptive.com/forum/